# SQL select last before by date and group by

Tags: mysql, sql

Using MySQL, I want to select all submissions (rows) which last submission is NULL and previous one is not, grouped by user_id.

If I consider the following example table, then the answer would be rows: 2, 5 and 7.

```
| ID | submission | date_submission | user_id |
|----|------------|-----------------|---------|
| 1  | lorem      | 2019-01-01      | 1       |
| 2  | ipsum      | 2019-01-02      | 1       |
| 3  | NULL       | 2019-01-03      | 1       |
| 4  | amet       | 2019-01-05      | 2       |
| 5  | NULL       | 2019-01-06      | 2       |
| 6  | sit        | 2019-01-04      | 1       |
| 7  | sed        | 2019-01-08      | 3       |
| 8  | elit       | 2019-01-07      | 4       |
| 9  | NULL       | 2019-01-09      | 3       |
```

MRE:

```
CREATE TABLE submissions (
  id int NOT NULL,
  submission varchar(45) NULL,
  date_submitted date NOT NULL,
  user_id int DEFAULT NULL
 );

insert into submissions (1, "lorem", 2019-01-01, 1);
insert into submissions (2, "ipsum", 2019-01-02, 1);
insert into submissions (3, NULL, 2019-01-03, 1);
insert into submissions (4, "amet", 2019-01-05, 2);
insert into submissions (5, NULL, 2019-01-06, 2);
insert into submissions (6, "sit", 2019-01-04, 1);
insert into submissions (7, "sed", 2019-01-08, 3);
insert into submissions (8, "elit", 2019-01-07, 4);
insert into submissions (9, NULL, 2019-01-09, 3);
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: which version of my sql you are using ..??

Comment: using MySQL version 8

Comment: Why should row 2 be in the results? user_id=1 has last submission in 2019-01-04 and it is not null.

Comment: Well, that should be included too, since I'm interested in the submissions before the last NULL, even though there might be ones after the NULL

Answer (score 0):

First get the last date with `null` submission for each user and then join to the table to get the rows of the previous dates.
By using `ROW_NUMBER()` get the last of these previous dates if it is not `null`:

```
select t.id, t.submission, t.date_submitted, t.user_id
from (
  select s.*,
    row_number() over (partition by s.user_id order by s.date_submitted desc) rn
  from submissions s inner join (
    select user_id,
      max(case when submission is null then date_submitted end) maxnulldate
    from submissions
    group by user_id
  ) g on g.user_id = s.user_id and g.maxnulldate > s.date_submitted  
) t
where t.rn = 1 and t.date_submitted is not null
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/m3cMB61xp94YpNPVHWahSz/1).
Results:

```
| id  | submission | date_submitted | user_id |
| --- | ---------- | -------------- | ------- |
| 2   | ipsum      | 2019-01-02     | 1       |
| 4   | amet       | 2019-01-05     | 2       |
| 7   | sed        | 2019-01-08     | 3       |
```

I guess you meant row number 4 and not 5 in your expected results, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag()` for this:

```
select s.*
from (select s.*,
             lag(submission) over (partition by user_id order by date_submitted) as prev_submission
      from submissions s
     ) s
where prev_submission is not null and submission is null;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1d0f29d5efa9eb7b5454c6947bc785b9) is a db<>fiddle.

EDIT:

It occurs to me that "last submission" really is the last submission for each user.  In that case, the above can be tweaked:

```
select s.*
from (select s.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id order by date_submitted desc) as seqnum,
             lag(submission) over (partition by user_id order by date_submitted) as prev_submission
      from submissions s
     ) s
where prev_submission is not null and submission is null and seqnum = 1;
```